# d3 selectAll.remove() is lagging versus d3.select.remove()

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, svg, contour

For a quick visual representation of the lag I am talking about:

http://tedxiao.me/ReachabilityD3/Iteration5/iteration5.html has no lag.

http://tedxiao.me/ReachabilityD3/Iteration6/iteration6.html has some lag.

In both cases, I read my data from a csv file (in one case, I use d3.csv, and the other case I use d3.text - this shouldn't be an issue.)

For the d3 WITH LAG:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
.interpolate("linear")
.x(function(d) { return xScale(d.x1); })
.y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y1); });

d3.selectAll("path").remove();

if ( <CASE 1>) {
        d3.csv(<FIRST FILE>, function(mydata) {
            svg.append("path")
            .datum(mydata)
            .attr("d", line);
        });
    d3.csv(<SECOND FILE>, function(mydata) {
        svg.append("path")
        .datum(mydata)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);
    });
} else { <CASE 2>
    d3.csv(<THIRD FILE>, function(mydata){
        svg.append("path")
        .datum(mydata)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);
    });
}
```

For the d3 WITHOUT LAG:

```
d3.text(<FIRST FILE>, function(text) {
            var data = d3.csv.parseRows(text).map(function(row) {
                return row.map(function(value) {
                    return -value;
                });
            });
            // console.log(data);
            var cliff = -1000;
            data.push(d3.range(data[0].length).map(function() {
                return cliff;
            }));
            data.unshift(d3.range(data[0].length).map(function() {
                return cliff;
            }));
            data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.push(cliff);
                d.unshift(cliff);
            });
            var c = new Conrec,
                xs = d3.range(0, data.length),
                ys = d3.range(0, data[0].length),
                zs = [i],
                width = 300,
                height = 300,
                x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]).domain([0,
                    data.length
                ]),
                y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]).domain([0,
                    data[0].length
                ]);

            c.contour(data, 0, xs.length - 1, 0, ys.length - 1, xs,
                ys, zs.length, zs);
```

The above code is all using conrec.js to find the contours of the z-function in a particular .csv file. The subsequent contour is equivalent to the contours I am directly using through the other method (contours stored as .csv files)

```
    d3.select("svg").remove();
    var test = d3.select("#contour").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(c.contourList()) //Contour from conrec.js
        .enter().append("path")
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) {
                return x(d.x);
            })
            .y(function(d) {
                return y(d.y);
            }));
```

Is this enough information to figure out why one of the d3 approaches has some lag while switching between contours?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "switching between contours" but, at least on a recent iMac using Safari 9, I see no latency in either example when changing the values of the inputs.

Comment: Same here with Opera. I don't notice any lag.

Comment: Do the contours have a slight "flash" when you switch from one to another? (I believe this flash is the remove operation and then the append operation)

Answer (score 3):

The reason is the processing of the files takes some time and the update is made asynchronously while in the correct case you make a synchronous update using already supplied data.

Comment: I think the case with "already supplied data" (the one that is currently without lag) is also asynchronous as well. I didn't post some code, which goes with the processing method that doesn't have lag currently. I have updated the main post with this code.

Comment: I think both are aynchronous, however, I think too that it's because it's not updating, it's processing files again. The "no-lag" version updates the data that was supplied before.